# Can the Files application in 18.04 search across links?

Tags: files, search

In trying to find the file `/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/wakeup` with the Files application search function, I couldn't find it when I started the search at the bus, USB or devices levels. But if I started at the usb1 level it showed up. Now usb1 is the only link in the above path, so I'm guessing Files search can't handle symbolic links. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can follow them while searching but is not smart enough to follow them in a search argument. If you see the screencap below, the links shown in the terminal take it back up three directories as shown in the upper part of the search results.

This search was started in Files at /.

[image]